# How to modify datatype from BIGSERIAL to String?

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase

I'm try to execute this sql:

```
ALTER TABLE a_table ALTER COLUMN a_id TYPE VARCHAR(255) USING (a_id::VARCHAR(255))
```

where a_id is BIGSERIAL, but getting error:

> ERROR: identity column type can only be smallint, integer, or bigint

In a table I have ID(bigserial too), using BIGSERIAL for a_id was mistake(it's not constraint)

UPD: I can't drop column for recreate because of data in this column

Comment: Please update the question with the original table DDL and the number of rows in the table. Are there any foreign key references to this table? These details significantly infuence the choice of approach when altering a column's data type.

Comment: 1) `BIGSERIAL` is not a type is basically a macro per [Serial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL), so you need to more then just change the underlying type `bigint`. 2) Why do want to change it to `varchar`? Why not just drop the `sequence` and leave the values as `bigint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `alter` statement on a [`bigserial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column [wouldn't](https://dbfiddle.uk/cnt8HKv0) trigger that error. You likely created the column as `bigint generated by default as identity` which acts similarly to `bigserial`, but isn't the same thing.

If that was put in place by accident, you just need to lift the identity constraint, after which your `alter` will work just fine, keeping all data intact, only mapped to the new type: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cnt8HKv0)

```sql
ALTER TABLE a_table ALTER COLUMN a_id DROP IDENTITY;
ALTER TABLE a_table ALTER COLUMN a_id TYPE VARCHAR(255) USING (a_id::VARCHAR(255));
```

See the note at the beginning of the [section on serial types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) in the doc:

> This section describes a PostgreSQL-specific way to create an autoincrementing column. Another way is to use the SQL-standard identity column feature, described at **[CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)**.